# Download data from S3 Server-side encryption enabled bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, encryption, server-side

I created an S3 Bucket with server-side encryption enabled using S3-managed keys.
Now I need to download the data using python script, but also need to decrypt as it gets downloaded.

Following is my code:

```
#Creating Session With Boto3.
session = boto3.Session(
    aws_access_key_id='ID',
    aws_secret_access_key='KEY'
)

#Creating S3 Resource From the Session.
s3 = session.resource('s3')
my_bucket = s3.Bucket(BUCKET_NAME)

for my_bucket_object in my_bucket.objects.filter(Prefix='DIRECTORY_NAME/'):
...
```

But it is downloading encrypted data.

Comment: If you download the object using the AWS CLI, does the file contents appear any different?

Answer (score 4):

It is not downloading encrypted data. The encryption and decryption process for Server-Side Encryption with S3-managed keys is totally transparent to users. It is only **encrypted at rest**. You will *never* see the encrypted version of the object.

If you are seeing encrypted data, then that is what the object contained when it was uploaded to S3.